# Writing udev rules for 3G USB dongle

Tags: hardware

I have a 3G USB dongle (Huawei K3715) for receiving SMS. After each reboot it changes the interface names. I wrote a udev rule but it is not working. I don't know why.
Can you have a look and say what is wrong?

Thanks.

lsusb:

`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem`

/etc/udev/rules.d/20_3gusb-local.rules:

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1001", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", SYMLINK+="smsphone"`

I restart the rules daemon with `udevadm control --reload-rules` or reboot it doesn't create a symlink /dev/smsphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I had my difficulties. The problem is that the UDEV rule does not work like this. You can not mix-and-match attributes from multiple parent devices.

But with this trick (seperate idVendor/idProdct and bInterfaceNumber) I've found on net it works.

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/40_umts.rules
# Symlink generating for UMTS-Stick

ACTION!="add", GOTO="umts_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="tty" GOTO="umts_rules_end"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1001", GOTO="umts_rules_begin"
GOTO="umts_rules_end"
LABEL="umts_rules_begin"

# generating SYMLINKs 
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", SYMLINK+="smsphone"

LABEL="umts_rules_end"
```

---

Update (12.04.2017)

I have found a clearer solution based on this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78764) that I would like to share. ;-)

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/40_umts.rules
# Symlink generating for UMTS-Stick

# note bInterfaceNumber
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"

# adding symlink for modem
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", \
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1001", \
    ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}=="00", SYMLINK+="smsphone"

# adding symlink for modem diag
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", \
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1001", \
    ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}=="01", SYMLINK+="modem_diag"
```